# Dart\Flutter Model Relationship from Json Data

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have two json files that I retrieved via an **api**. I want to create a relationship between the product and the category for display in my product listview the **name** of the category instead of the **id** of the category.

here i have an example of my first json file which contains all the products.

`listing.json`

```
[
   {
      "id":1461267313,
      "category_id":4,
      "title":"Statue homme",
      "description":"...",
      "price":140.00,
      "images_url":{
         "small":"...",
         "thumb":"..."
      },
      "creation_date":"2019-11-05T15:56:59+0000",
      "is_urgent":false
   },
   {
      "id":1691247255,
      "category_id":8,
      "title":"Pc portable hp elitebook 820 g1 core i5 4 go ram 250 go hdd",
      "description":"...",
      "price":199.00,
      "images_url":{
         "small":"...",
         "thumb":"..."
      },
      "creation_date":"2019-10-16T17:10:20+0000",
      "is_urgent":false
   },
]
```

and there the second json file which contains the categories

`categories.json`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Véhicule"
  },

  //from 1 to 11

  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Enfants"
  }
]
```

I created a **product model** and a **category model**

`product.dart`

```
class Product {
  int? id;
  int? categoryId;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  double? price;
  ImagesUrl? imagesUrl;
  String? creationDate;
  bool? isUrgent;

  Product(
      {this.id,
      this.categoryId,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.price,
      this.imagesUrl,
      this.creationDate,
      this.isUrgent});
}
```

`category.dart`

```
class Category {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  Category({this.id, this.name});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I created a map to match the category id of my product to the name field of my class category. I get it back with the key like that. `productByCat` return type is `Map<int, String>`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataProduct!.length; i++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < dataCategory!.length; y++) {
           if (dataProduct?[i]['category_id'] == dataCategory?[y]['id']) {
              productByCat[dataProduct?[i]['category_id']] = dataCategory?[y]['name'];
           }
     }
}
return productByCat;
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new class ProductItem. After converting json file add both product & category in an order to the new class.
`class ProductItem { final Product product; final Category category; ProductItem({required this.product, required this.category}); }`

Comment: how i instantiate this class ?